# How to prevent program uninstall by administrator from registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, operating-systems, administrator, uninstall

I have a way to control access to the registry. I am looking for a way to prevent the administrator from uninstalling any program.

I am aware that there is a way to prevent users from uninstalling from the start menu using the registry, but I have been unable to find a solution for preventing uninstalling in general from the registry.

Is there a way to prevent general uninstalling, not just from the start menu, using the registry?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem Why do you want to do that

Comment: Look up **TrustedInstaller**, which MS uses for that purpose. There are ways around that, though.

Comment: @Gantendo I want to make it very difficult for myself to uninstall a particular app. I know that if there were an edit to the registry that I could make to prevent uninstall, it would accomplish what I want. Not sure how your article applies in this case.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I looked through some articles, but it seems I wouldn't know how to use it for my purposes. Like I said in the comment above, I have limited knowledge, and I just wanted to know if there was a registry edit I could make to prevent general uninstallation.

Comment: @SebastianLinde Which program? I had something similar where I wrote 2 scripts, each constantly making sure the other existed and was running. That way, if one of them got deleted or closed, the other would instantly recreate and start it.

Comment: You can ofcourse remove it from the add/remove software list, and delete uninstall.exe https://www.uvm.edu/~bnelson/computer/windows95/usetheregistrytoremoveitemsfrominstalluninstalllist.html

Comment: @Gantendo thanks for your help. I wouldn't want to say, as it is a little embarrassing. Suffice it to say that I do not want to make it completely impossible to remove it. I think, though I am not sure, that doing the add/remove and delete uninstall move would make it so that I can't remove it ever. Am I right?

Comment: @SebastianLinde It would still be able to be uninstalled if you had removed it from the Add/Remove software list. It would just require a bit more knowhow because the normal method would no longer work.

Comment: @Gantendo would it be correct to say that if there was a registry edit that prevented all uninstalls and I blocked myself from the registry, there would be no way to uninstall unless I gained access to the registry?

Comment: https://www.mobigyaan.com/disable-users-uninstalling-apps-windows-10

Comment: @SebastianLinde Not really, no. Remember uninstalling and making sure a program stops working are two different things. And I could easily achieve the second objective without access to the registry, even if uninstalling was not possible.

Comment: What I would do is write 2 scripts, 1 that starts the program when it is exited, and another to make sure the first script keeps running.

Comment: @Gantendo you just added to my problem! But still, it seems like you agree that my registry scenario would take care of half the problem. I saw the article above. The problem I have is that I do not know if the uninstall from start is enough. Aren't I able to just go to the control panel and uninstall from there? I wish I knew how to do that (writing scripts). Right now, I am just getting acquainted with the registry.

Comment: Yep. You could use a local account with no administrator rights. That way you wouldn't be able to install or uninstall anything, but that literally means anything.

Comment: @Gantendo I need to be able to install, which is why I was wondering if there was a solution through the registry. It seems like there isn't. There is, but for the uninstall from Start, but there isn't for the more general case.

Comment: @SebastianLinde The only thing I can think of that might have the functionality you require is some kind of parental control software but because I don't have kids I never had a reason to look into that kinda stuff. If you know how to write software you may be able to write your own solution.

Comment: It's not possible to prevent an user from doing something on a machine where they have elevated permissions.Even if a key is owned by TrustedInstaller it is possible to change the ownership of that key as an Administrator. There are folders on Windows, where by default TrustedInstaller owns them (i.e. WindowsApps), but an experience user can always change that ownership.There are literally hundreds of questions, on this very website, that ask our help to with issues by changing the permission of WindowsApps.I can uninstall any application you install and I know virtually nothing about Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that administrators have such power. But I also know that for my problem, given my limited knowledge, if there was a way to "turn off" uninstalling from the registry, I would not be able to uninstall the program. Is there such a way?